# POST Form action not working properly [Django]

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm new to Django and I'm trying to fill the contentString of a Google Maps Marker with the following content:

```
for (i=0; i< Object.keys(j).length; i++){
  venue_name = j[i]['name']
  contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">'+j[i]['name']+'</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>'+j[i]['name']+'</b></p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: '+j[i]['name']+', <a href="https://www.google.es/#q='+j[i]['name']+" "+city+'">'+
        'Más información</a> '+
        '</p>'+
    '<button onclick="calculateAndDisplayRoute('+ j[i]['lat'] +','+ j[i]['long'] +')">Ir!</button>'+
    '<li><a href = "{% url 'detail' 'venue_name' %}">Ver comentarios</a>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
```

The main idea is that the href link will send the venue_name variable to the detail view so it can retrieve the requested information from de data base. The problem is, venue_name is interpreted as a string, but if I remove the quotes then I get this error: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['venuesApp/(?P\w+)/$']

It should be the correct sintax if I'm not mistaken, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the fact that the whole HTML code is inside a JS string. I have another POST form outside the JS script code and it works just fine.

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^(?P<venue_name>\w+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

EDIT:

detail view:

```
def detail(request, venue_name):
if request.POST.has_key('text'):
    text=request.POST['text']
    user=request.user
    Review.objects.create(venue=venue_name,user=user,lat_long="",text=text)
try:
    p=Review.objects.filter(venue=venue_name)
    review_list = list(p.values())
except Review.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("No reviews available.")
context={ 'review_list':review_list, 'venue_name':venue_name}
return render(request,'venuesApp/detail.html',context)
```

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8GsN.png)

Comment: oh sorry I wrongly understand the question. can you try this  `'<li><a href = "{% url ' + "detail" + ' '+ venue_name +' %}">Ver comentarios</a>'`

Comment: what is happening when you navigate to this page `localhost:8000/venuesApp/somepage` ?

Comment: It renders the detail page for whatever 'somepage' is

Comment: Can you `console.log(venue_name)` Chances are this should be empty sometimes and thus error

Comment: I edited a screenshot into the post. Doesn't seem to be empty at any point though

Comment: Okay i'm out of options. May be someone will help

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways. I'll keep trying

Comment: The error does seem to indicate that there is no venue_name variable present in your template. Could you add the code for the detail.html template?

Answer (score 0):

Try to render the URL using a placeholder, and then replace it in javascript:

```
for (i=0; i< Object.keys(j).length; i++){
    var venue_url = "{% url 'detail' venue_name=XXXXX %}".replace('XXXXX', j[i]['name']);
    contentString = '...' + 
    '<a href = "' + venue_url + '">Ver comentarios</a>' + 
    '...'
```

it's not that elegant, but works.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get the following error from the django debugger: Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'venue_name': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['venuesApp/(?P<venue_name>\\w+)/$']

Comment: So far the only way I've found to solve this is to manually set the url like this: '<li><a href = "/venuesApp/'+venue_name+'">Ver comentarios</a>'+

Comment: Strange, try surrounding the placeholder in quotes: `"{% url 'detail' venue_name='XXXXX' %}"`

Comment: Doesn seem to work either. This was a college assignment actually, went to see my teacher and basically told me to set the url manually. It's strange though, there should be a way to do it using Django url